# Getting uncertain app permissions on my phone which shouldn't get involved

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have these permissions declared on my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

What's interesting that I have different permissions showing in app info on my phone (I haven't declared USB write and read). I did have write and read permissions, but I have deleted it. Maybe that is the problem? Here is how it looks:

[image]

> My mobile antivirus Avast is also complaining about malicious
>   permissions:

[image]

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Are you attaching any Android library projects or AARs to your app? They can contribute permissions through manifest merging, as they may need those permissions for those libraries to function.

Comment: I had a library which used <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> I deleted that, but still after rebuilding my project and deleting my app from phone, I'm still getting same permissions.

Comment: Android Studio or Eclipse? If it's Android Studio, look for the manifest merger reports (in `build/outputs/apk/`), as it may give you an indication of where the problem is coming from. Also, what is your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: I am using Android Studio. I checked manifest merger report and found this:
`uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ADDED from com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.0:8:5
 android:name
  ADDED from com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.0:8:22`
But I checked that library's Manifest and that permission was deleted. Also that merger file was modified couple of days from now. My `minSdkVersion is 9` and `targetSdkversion is 19`

Comment: Hmmm... try Project > Clean Project from the Android Studio main menu, to try to get it to re-perform the manifest merger.

Comment: Well, I cleaned my project by Build > Clean Project but I think it's not a case. Still nothing, it was modified 01.10

Comment: OK, try Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files, then Build > Clean Project again. Somehow, you need to get that manifest merger process to run again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68760/discussion-between-linkas-and-commonsware).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed it. Manifest merger report updates, but it still shows that it adds permission despite the fact I deleted it from library project.